# how to remove double quotes from null in dataframe

Tags: python

I'm trying to replace blank with null and converting the dataframe and writing it as parquet file using awswrangler. This parquet loads in Snowflake table as JSON file. In Snowflake table null is coming with double quotes "null" instead json object null(without double quotes). It will be simple thing I'm missing, any help will be much appreciated

**Expected JSON output null without double quotes**

```
{'name': 'Jane', 'age': '25', 'city': null}
```

**Code tried**

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": ["John", "Jane", "Raj", "Mike"],
    "age": [30, 25, "", 35],
    "city": ["New York", "", "", "Chicago"]
})

metadata = {
    "eventVersion": "3",
    "producedBy": "Service",
}
json_list = []
column_names = df.columns.tolist()

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    payload_dict = row.to_dict()
    for key, value in payload_dict.items():
        if value == '':
            payload_dict[key] = 'null'
        elif isinstance(value, float):
            payload_dict[key] = '{:.2f}'.format(value).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
        else:
            payload_dict[key] = str(value)

    output_dict = {}
    output_dict.update(metadata)
    output_dict['payload'] = payload_dict
    json_list.append(output_dict)

df_final = pd.DataFrame(json_list)

for _, row in df_final.iterrows():
    print(row)

output_file_name = output_path+'parquet/'+fn.replace('csv','parquet')
awswrangler.s3.to_parquet(df_final, f's3://{input_bucket}/{output_file_name}', dataset=False, index=False)
```

Comment: `'null'` is a string not a null value.

Comment: Use `None`, not `'null'`.

Comment: Yes how replace null value instead of ‘null’ string

Answer (score 0):

The `json` module associates the JSON value `null` with the Python value `None`:

```
>>> json.dumps(None)
'null'
>>> print(json.loads('null'))
None
```